# Best way to implement role based authorization for given situation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

My application uses API Gateway with lambda functions and a JWT authorizer. I do not use identity pools at all.

My user gets their id and access token, and the id token contains a custom attribute for their role (admin/user). I send the user's access token with each request.

My idea was to just use the `GetUser` Cognito SDK method (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-cognito-identity-provider/classes/getusercommand.html), check the user's role, and allow/deny the request based on that in my lambda endpoint functions. The issue I am having is that it is really slow and it is increasing my lambda execution times a lot.

What would be a better alternative? Sending the id token with every request instead of the access token since it contains the role directly? Setting up a custom authorizer? Or something else?